# How can I tell whether an SMT/SMD Capacitor is oriented with plates horizontal or vertical?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, layout, ceramic, mlcc

[This article](https://www.mouser.com/applications/rf-wireless-capacitors/) talks about mounting capacitors with the electrodes parallel or perpendicular to this microstrip indicating that "By mounting the capacitor vertically, that is, with the electrodes perpendicular to the microstrip, the first parallel resonance will not be present thereby significantly extending the usable bandpass."

Sounds great, maybe everyone should all mount them vertically.  But how can I tell?

Is there an industry standard for showing how plates in the SMT cap are oriented?

Some datasheets have pictures like this that help if the cap is thinner it is wide, how can you tell if it is a square-rectanguloid instead of being flattish in one dimension?

[image: SMT/SMD capacitor diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (or anyway, historically could) buy specially marked ones from ATC (American Technical Ceramics, and now owned by AVX, which is in turn owned by Kyocera) if you want to do this. Or simply choose capacitors that are not square in cross-section, so the orientation can be distinguished even without markings.

Practically, most MLCC's are not marked for this, and are probably loaded in their tapes the wrong way, and we just accept the reduced performance in return for lower cost (because the parts can go into the tape in the same orientation they are diced out from the greenboard they are manufactured on).

If you want to do this with unmarked parts you will probably have to do hand assembly and just be careful to turn them 90 degrees after taking them out of the tape (and tossing any that you lose track of the orientation of).

Comment: Great answer.  Is it safe to say that non-square-crosssection caps are horizontally oriented when laid flat?

Comment: @KJ7LNW, I don't know. Read the datasheet.